# Java hashMap .getValue() returning false when value is there

Tags: java, hashmap

when .getValue() called for the entry "Jacob" I am getting a *false* when the value is there.

Error located at third-to-last line

Can anyone please help?

```
public class MCV {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee employee1 = new Employee(111, "Jacob", "Canada");  

    HashMap<Integer, Employee> employees = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();

    employees.put(employee1.getEmployeeId(),employee1);

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    for (Entry<Integer, Employee> entry: employees.entrySet()){
          properties.put(entry.getKey().toString(),  entry.getValue().toString());
    }


        System.out.println("Does Hashmap contain 111 as key: " + employees.containsKey(111));
        System.out.println("Does hashmap contain Jacob as value: " + employees.containsValue(String.valueOf("Jacob")));

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you used your IDE's debugger to further delve into why your code is not behaving as expected?

Comment: IDE not seeing a bug unfortunately.

Comment: Also, when asking about debugging non-behaving code, we all would benefit, both you and us, if you could create and post a valid [mcve] code post, not the whole program and not a non-compilable snippet, but rather a compilable, runnable program that shows us your problem directly.

Comment: `employees` is a `HashMap<Integer, Employee>`. Each value is an `Employee` reference, not a string - so `employees.containsValue("Jacob")` would *always* return false, regardless of the content of the map.

Comment: Thank you, currently attempting

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're testing if the Map contains the value "Jacob", a String, when it doesn't hold String values. It holds Employee values. You need to do a more intense test of containment, one that tests if it holds an Employee that has a first name "Jacob"

Note that Map declaration: `HashMap<Integer, Employee>` where the 2nd generic parameter is `Employee`. So testing for equality to a String will never work.

Perhaps if Jacob is held by a firstName field and accessed via `getFirstName()` something like this could work:

```
boolean foo = employees.values().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getFirstName().equals("Jacob"));
System.out.println(foo);
```

If you don't have a `getFirstName()` method, then perhaps `.getName()`, not sure as we don't know the structure of your Employee class yet.

Comment: Thank you, once getFirstName method created and used with boolean foo, output is as expected. Perhaps for next time HashMap<Integer, String> would allow usage of .getValue() as you were saying?

Comment: @Christian: yes, a `Map<Integer, String>` would allow testing of **the complete String**, but don't do this as you'd be losing information. Keep your Map as a `Map<Integer, Employee>`